How to replace a value including the column in a structure
When I use DataFrame.replace, it doesn't replace the values that are in a structure.
In this example, it doesn't replace the value of my_struct.struct_string:
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

data = [
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null"}),
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("a_string", StringType(), True),
    StructField(
        "my_struct",
        StructType([
           StructField("struct_string", StringType(), True),
        ]),
        True
    )
])


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)


df = df.replace("null", None)

df_astring = df.filter(col("a_string").isNotNull())
df_struct_string = df.filter(col("my_struct.struct_string").isNotNull())

print("My df_astring")
df_astring.show()
print("My df_struct_string")
df_struct_string.show()

It print:
My df_astring
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
+--------+---------+

My df_struct_string
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
|    null|   {null}|
+--------+---------+

Note that I also tried df = df.replace("null", None, ["a_string", "my_struct.struct_string"]), but I get the exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Nested field my_struct.struct_string is not supported.
The solution needs to be dynamic, so it won't precise manually the column name that are string.
The expected output is:
My df_astring
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
+--------+---------+

My df_struct_string
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
+--------+---------+


can you add sample input data the expected output, it helps in testing

I just added it.

The answer of @samhita works, but it is way slower when the dataset is big.
I also included the support of list.
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, Row, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
from typing import Any

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("replace_null_example").getOrCreate()

# Sample DataFrame
data = [
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
]

# Define the schema with three levels of nested StructType fields
schema = StructType([
    StructField("a_string", StringType(), True), 
    StructField(
        "my_struct",  # First level struct
        StructType([
            StructField(
                "struct_string",  # Second level struct
                StringType(), 
                True
            ),
            StructField(
                "nested_struct",  # Third level struct
                StructType([
                    StructField("nested_field", StringType(), True) 
                ]),
                True
            )
        ]),
        True
    )
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

def remplace_null_values(line: Row) -> dict[str, Any]:
    line_dict = line.asDict(True)

    def transformation(data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            return {key: transformation(value) for key, value in data.items()}
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            return [transformation(item) for item in data]
        elif data == "null":
            return None
        else:
            return data

    line_dict = transformation(line_dict)
    return line_dict

new_df: DataFrame = df.rdd.map(remplace_null_values).toDF(df.schema)

df_astring = new_df.filter(col("a_string").isNotNull())
df_struct_string = new_df.filter(col("my_struct.nested_struct.nested_field").isNotNull())

print("My df_astring")
df_astring.show(truncate=False)
print("My df_struct_string")
df_struct_string.show(truncate=False)


I have done some extra level processing, to replace the nulls in structype.
Function replace_null_in_struct iterates over each field and subfield of the structType in the schema and checks whether it is null, then replaces with None.
The caveat would be if you have multiple level of nested structType data structure, a recursive approach would be needed, let me know if that is the case.
But for now with the schema you provided, it returns the expected output.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("replace_null_example").getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null"}),
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("a_string", StringType(), True),
    StructField(
        "my_struct",
        StructType([
           StructField("struct_string", StringType(), True),
        ]),
        True
    )
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

def replace_null_in_struct(df):
    for field in df.schema.fields:
        field_name = field.name

        if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
            struct_columns = []
            for subfield in field.dataType.fields:
                subfield_name = subfield.name
                updated_subfield = F.when(F.col(f"{field_name}.{subfield_name}") == "null", None).otherwise(F.col(f"{field_name}.{subfield_name}"))
                struct_columns.append(updated_subfield.alias(subfield_name))
            
            df = df.withColumn(field_name, F.struct(*struct_columns))

        elif isinstance(field.dataType, StringType):
            df = df.withColumn(
                field_name,
                F.when(F.col(field_name) == "null", None).otherwise(F.col(field_name))
            )
    
    return df

df = replace_null_in_struct(df)

df_astring = df.filter(F.col("a_string").isNotNull())
df_struct_string = df.filter(F.col("my_struct.struct_string").isNotNull())

print("My df_astring")
df_astring.show(truncate=False)
print("My df_struct_string")
df_struct_string.show(truncate=False)

Output
My df_astring
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
+--------+---------+

My df_struct_string
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
+--------+---------+

EDIT : As per comment data structure might be nested, so included recursion in below code.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("replace_null_example").getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
    ("null", {"struct_string": "null", "nested_struct": {"nested_field": "null"}}),
]

# Define the schema with three levels of nested StructType fields
schema = StructType([
    StructField("a_string", StringType(), True), 
    StructField(
        "my_struct",  # First level struct
        StructType([
            StructField(
                "struct_string",  # Second level struct
                StringType(), 
                True
            ),
            StructField(
                "nested_struct",  # Third level struct
                StructType([
                    StructField("nested_field", StringType(), True) 
                ]),
                True
            )
        ]),
        True
    )
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

def replace_null_in_struct(df):
    def recursive_replace(column_name, dtype):
        """Recursively replace 'null' with None in the specified column."""
        if isinstance(dtype, StructType):  
            struct_columns = []
            for subfield in dtype.fields:
                subfield_name = subfield.name
                struct_columns.append(
                    recursive_replace(f"{column_name}.{subfield_name}", subfield.dataType).alias(subfield_name)
                )
            return F.struct(*struct_columns)
        
        elif isinstance(dtype, StringType): 
            return F.when(F.col(column_name) == "null", None).otherwise(F.col(column_name))
        
        return F.col(column_name)

    for field in df.schema.fields:
        field_name = field.name
        df = df.withColumn(field_name, recursive_replace(field_name, field.dataType))
    
    return df

df = replace_null_in_struct(df)

df_astring = df.filter(F.col("a_string").isNotNull())
df_struct_string = df.filter(F.col("my_struct.nested_struct.nested_field").isNotNull())

print("My df_astring")
df_astring.show(truncate=False)
print("My df_struct_string")
df_struct_string.show(truncate=False)

Output with recursion
My df_astring
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
+--------+---------+

My df_struct_string
+--------+---------+
|a_string|my_struct|
+--------+---------+
+--------+---------+


Yes, replace_null_in_struct would need to be recursive, because if there is 2 nested structs, the solution won't work.

ok, thanks for letting me know, I will check

I have edited code to include recursion and tested it with multi level structType

Thanks! It work, but it was pretty slow when the dataset was big. I found a alternative.
